# rails 3, trying to confirm that an email address is in the dbm, but getting a wrong number of args error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model-validation

My source is at: https://gist.github.com/f01685376a02a577a9cb

the method in question:

```
def is_valid_email?(address)
  User.find_by_email(address)
end
```

I think the solution is to change the value for `User.find_by_email(address)` to something like `User.find_by_email(next_approver_email) = (address)` but I know that doesn't work.

`Next_approver_email` is what we are tying to check against the `user.email` db column

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the email into `is_valid_email?` at the end of line 5

```
def validate_each(approval, attribute, value)
   approval.errors[attribute] << "must be a valid e-mail address in our system" unless is_valid_email?(value)
end
```

Comment: I thought that to, and tried it but it returns an undefined local variable or method `address' on line 5.

Comment: You need to use `is_valid_email?(value)`, not `is_valid_email?(address)`